# %run on files with space in names

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the magic command %run on a notebook which has spaces in the filename.

```
%run Crazy Code.ipynb
ERROR:root:File `'Crazy.py'` not found.
```

Is there a way around this without changing the file name? 
I have a lot of notebooks whose names have spaces in between words; I find it easier to read.

Comment: Have you tried `%run "Crazy Code.ipynb"`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried it with a different notebook and it wasn't working, but it seems to be working now. I will test it out with a few different notebooks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File names with spaces in them are typically wrapped in double quotes to solve this problem. In your case, this would be:

`%run "Crazy Code.ipynb"`

Comment: It seems, that  I need double quotes not single quotes! That was the mistake I made earlier. If you can update that into your answer as a caution, that would be very helpful to others.